# Do convenience constructor increase the size of the app...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, constructor, autorelease

I am pretty much sure they do... but just wanted to confirm... for instance look at the following code..

```
- (void)reset {
NSNumber *zero = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
[self setCount:zero];
}
```

now this returns an autoreleased object which gets added to the autorelease pool of the app and thus increasing its size...

and this will not be freed unless the app is terminated..?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory is freed the next pass through the application's main event loop.

The exact time depends on when your application finishes executing your code and returns to the event loop. It's during the event loop that, among the tasks that are scheduled, is emptying (draining) the application's autorelease pool.

If you're concerned about autorelease pools gaining in size, you could employ your own autorelease pools strategically.

Comment: I am looking for the exact time , I mean what triggers the pass ..?

Comment: Adding on to what @trudyscousin said, [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] and other common objects are compiled down to a singleton at runtime to save memory.

Comment: @trudyscousin You don't know exactly when the main event loop will run, but you can use, as a general idea, that once any code you write is done executing, the main loop is running.  Picture it this way.  The main event loop is running, and when it needs to, it calls your code to do something.  When that call into your code is done, the event loop runs again.  That's not exactly what happens, but close enough to get the picture...  Basically, once the entry into your code is done, the main event loop is running again.